# Large Scale Processing of S3 Images

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, airflow

I have roughly 80tb of images hosted in an S3 bucket which I need to send to an API for image classification. Once the images are classified, the API will forward the results to another endpoint.

Currently, I am thinking of using boto to interact with S3 and perhaps Apache airflow to download these images in batches and forward them to the classification API, which will forward the results of the classification to a web app for display.

In the future I want to automatically send any new image added to the S3 bucket to the API for classification. To achieve this I am hoping to use AWS lambda and S3 notifications to trigger this function.

Would this be the best practice for such a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to provide more information about "download these images in batches" and "send to an API": can we assume that you either (1) will be working with a fleet of machines inside AWS, or (2) have a multi-gigabit connection to the Internet?

Comment: By 'in batches', I mean posting the images to the api in the same script that downloads the images and once the post is completed deleting the image from disk. I can use a fleet of machines on AWS.

Answer (score 1):

For your future scenarios, yes, that approach would be sensible:

- Configure **Amazon S3 Events** to trigger an AWS Lambda function when a new object is created
- The **Lambda function** can download the object (to `/tmp/`) and **call the remote API**
- Make sure the Lambda function **deletes the temporary file** before exiting since the Lambda container might be reused and there is a 500MB storage limit

Please note that the Lambda function will trigger on a single object, rather than in batches.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply John. I assume this would work if 20000 images were uploaded. It would just trigger 20000 lambda calls?

Comment: Yes. A Lambda function will be triggered immediately when an image object is created in Amazon S3. So, 20,000 images uploaded would trigger 20,000 Lambda functions. There are limits on the number of concurrent functions executing that would cause them to queue, but I presume your uploads will be spread over time.